# Biblatex: organize order of elements in the reference

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` to create my references in my document. The problem is that I can't make the reference follow an order. For instance they appear like this:

[image: What I have]

When actualy I need them to show in this order:

```
Author, Title, Publish Date, Magazine, Local, "Disponivel em: " <URL>
```

My code is shown below, you can see that some blocks I got from questions already answered here, but none seemed to solve the order of the elements:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,a4paper,oneside]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[
    hmarginratio = 1:1,
    left = 3cm,
    right = 2cm,
    top = 3cm,
    bottom = 2cm
    ]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathptmx} % text in Times New Roman

\usepackage[babel = other,
    backend = biber,
    style = authoryear,
    bibstyle = authoryear,
    firstinits = true, % abbreviate author's first name
    sorting = none
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refer.bib}
\bibsetup{
    \setcounter{abbrvpenalty}{0}
    \setcounter{highnamepenalty}{0}
    \setcounter{lownamepenalty}{0}
}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

% The following code is to separate the author from the year with a comma
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

% The following code is to put author's name in capital letters
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

% Format text in references
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{url}{Disponível em: $<$\url{#1}$>$}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{url}{Disponível em: $<$\url{#1}$>$}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\textbf{#1}}

% Year without parenthesis
\renewcommand{\bibopenparen}{\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand{\bibcloseparen}{\addcomma\addspace}

% #############################################
% The following code is to make et al appear in italics

\renewbibmacro*{name:andothers}{% Based on name:andothers from biblatex.def
    \ifboolexpr{
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
        and
        test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}
        {\finalandcomma}
        {}%
        \andothersdelim\bibstring[\emph]{andothers}}
    {}}

% #############################################

% #############################################
% The following code is to highlight the author and year when cited in text.:

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}

\savebibmacro{cite}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}

% #############################################

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
    {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
            \printfield{prefixnumber}%
            \printfield{labelnumber}}}
    {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
        \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
        \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
        \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
    \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{date+extrayear}{%
    \printtext[parens]%
}{%
    \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
    \printtext%
}{}{}

\urlstyle{rm} % make urls appear with roman font

\begin{document}
    Testing something (\cite{Drumm}). Other test (\cite{Guarnieri}). And maybe this is the final one (\cite{Manavella}). Now it's the last one (\cite{daRosa}).

    \flushleft
    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=\uppercase{{Referências}}]
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

The references are:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@InProceedings{Guarnieri,
  author    = {M. Guarnieri},
  title     = {Looking Back to Electric Cars},
  booktitle = {2012 Third IEEE History of Electro-technology Conference (HISTELCON)},
  year      = {2012},
  pages     = {1-6},
  doi       = {10.1109/HISTELCON.2012.6487583},
  keywords  = {electric vehicles;history;electric cars;nineteenth century;rechargeable battery;production technology;Electric;car;automobile;DC motor;rechargeable battery},
}

@Book{Manavella,
  title     = {Emissões Automotivas: Sistemas de Controle - Diagnóstico},
  publisher = {HM Autotrônica},
  year      = {2012},
  author    = {Humberto Manavella},
  url       = {http://www.hmautotron.eng.br/zip/c03-emiss-proccombust.pdf},
}

@Article{Drumm,
  author   = {Drumm, Fernanda Caroline and Gerhardt, Ademir Eloi and Fernandes, Gabriel D'Avila and Chagas, Patricia and Sucolotti, Mariana Scheffer and da Cunha Kemerich, Pedro Daniel},
  title    = {Poluição Atmosférica Proveniente da Queima de Combustíveis Derivados do Petróleo em Veículos Automotores},
  journal  = {Revista Eletrônica em Gestão, Educação e Tecnologia Ambiental},
  year     = {2014},
  location = {Brasil},
  volume   = {18},
  number   = {1},
  pages    = {66--78},
  url      = {https://periodicos.ufsm.br/index.php/reget/article/view/10537},
}

@Article{daRosa,
  author   = {da Rosa, Antonio Robson Oliveira e Gasparin, Fabiano Perin},
  title    = {Panorama da Energia Solar Fotovoltaica no Brasil},
  journal  = {Revista Brasileira de Energia Solar},
  year     = {2016},
  location = {Brasil},
  volume   = {7},
  number   = {2},
  pages    = {140--147},
  month    = dec,
  url      = {https://rbens.emnuvens.com.br/rbens/article/view/157},
}
```

Could anyone help to make the reference appear in the order I need?

Comment: There is [`biblatex-abnt`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-abnt) if you have to follow ABNT style.